# Execute Realm Query against multiple model classes

Tags: android, database, realm

I am using Realm database. I have an average of five models. I want to call all the models when I search. Is it possible?

```
ClassOne
ClassTwo
ClassThree
ClassFour
ClassFive
```

When querying is not one by one as follows.

```
RealmResult<ClassOne> list = realm.where(ClassOne.class).equelsTo("key", "a").findAll();
```

what kind of query I can make calls in all models?

Comment: A query is based on *one* model class, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this because every query return a RealmResuts of the type used on "Where"

The documentation says:

> Returns a typed RealmQuery, which can be used to query for specific objects of this type

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#where-java.lang.Class-